# How to view two dialog boxes on the linux console, running on the same time?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, dialog

I want to view on the Linux console two dialog windows on the same time.

I want a window that views the progress BAR, and the a second tailbox that view the logs are running.

The problem is that the dialog appears always in the center of the console.

What I want is

1. to view the two dialog boxes on the same time on the console,
2. while the progress bar is on the top of the screen,
3. and the the box should present down in the screen.

How to implement this?

How to place the dialog window up or down and not in the central?

```
    dialog --title "RUN TASKS FROM TEXT TABLE" --gauge "Please wait..." 10 70 0
    dialog --tailbox file.log 10 100
```

Answer (score 0):

### screen

You can do this with a terminal multiplexer like gnu [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) (also check out [byobu](http://byobu.co/) for something real fancy). It's like a text-mode window manager so you can split your terminal horizontally and run 2 independent "windows" inside it.

For example with screen:

```
$ screen
```

do <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and type your first cmd:

```
dialog --title "RUN TASKS FROM TEXT TABLE" --gauge "Please wait..." 10 70 0
```

<kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-I</kbd>,
<kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> and type your second cmd:

```
dialog --tailbox file.log 10 100
```

Which gives:

[image]

You can automate all this with a .screenrc file.
If you're new to screen google around a bit, there are lots of tutorials.